# How can I repair my code? Warning: a promise was created

Tags: javascript

For some time now I have such a mistake in the console and I do not really understand what is going on and how I should fix it. Error:

can someone show me how to write it better?

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /Users/pietrzakadrian/Desktop/bankApplicationOfficial/server/controllers/user.controller.js:119:16 but was not returned from it, see
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/Users/pietrzakadrian/Desktop/bankApplicationOfficial/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:29:9)
```

and this is my code and I added a comment to the line where there is supposed to be a mistake?

```
// Login Action
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  function getTodayDate() {
    const today = new Date();
    return today;
  }

  function getToken(userId) {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: userId,
      },
      env.SECRET_KEY,
      {
        expiresIn: '60min',
      },
    );
    return token;
  }

  User.findOne({
    where: {
      login: req.body.login,
    },
  })
    .then(isUser => {
      if (isUser) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, isUser.password)) {
          User.update( // <- this
            {
              last_present_logged: getTodayDate(),
            },
            { where: { login: req.body.login } },
          ).then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              token: getToken(isUser.id),
            });

          });
        } else {
          User.update(
            {
              last_failed_logged: getTodayDate(),
            },
            { where: { login: req.body.login } },
          ).then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
              error: 'Auth failed. The password is incorrect.',
              success: false,
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ error: 'Auth failed. User does not exist', success: false });
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      /* just ignore */
    });
};
```

Comment: Seems to me that you have a catch without a try.

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird's documentation (check out the examples at : [Warning explanations section](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it) says :

> This usually means that you simply forgot a return statement somewhere, which will cause a runaway promise that is not connected to any promise chain.